# TR hover affects BROTHER

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that goes like this:

```
<table>
   <tr class="anHour">
      <td class="hour" rowspan="3">9:00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="place">                                       
      <td>Place 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="place">
      <td>Place 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>                               
   </tr>
</table>
```

And i want two things:

1. Whenever the hover of tr.place is activated, it should affects tr.anHour (or td.hour) to activate its hover aswell.
2. Whenever the hover of tr.anHour (or td.hour) is activated, it should affects all tr.place to activate their hover aswell.

How can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: provide  the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it purely with CSS. You could change the styling of the `place` elements via a [general sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) (`.anHour:hover ~ .place { /* styles */}`, but you can't do the converse because you can't determine the styling of an *earlier* sibling based on the state of a *later* one.

Instead, you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to add/remove classes. That's not literally the same as activating `hover`, but it can have the same effect.

Here's an example using CSS for the first one and JavaScript for the second (so you can see both working):

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll(".place"),
  function(place) {
    place.addEventListener("mouseenter", handlePlaceMouseEnter);
    place.addEventListener("mouseleave", handlePlaceMouseLeave);
  }
);
function handlePlaceMouseEnter() {
  this.parentNode.querySelector(".anHour").classList.add("hover");
}
function handlePlaceMouseLeave() {
  this.parentNode.querySelector(".anHour").classList.remove("hover");
}
```

```css
.anHour:hover ~ .place, .place:hover {
  color: green;
}
.anHour:hover, .anHour.hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr class="anHour">
      <td class="hour" rowspan="3">9:00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="place">                                       
      <td>Place 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="place">
      <td>Place 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>                               
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i'm having problems with the hour. If i'm over the hour, the places gets green, but if i'm over a place, hour does not get blue... Pretty strange. Any tip?

Comment: @Zariweya: Well, the code above doesn't have that problem, so I'd look closely at the code that does have that problem and compare it to the above to identify what's different.

Comment: Yeah, i've been doing that since yesterday. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
.anHour : hover ~ .place {background: #9bcc41 }
```

~ is an successor siblings selector which works only for successors , for previous siblings you need to add "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" and  try jquery function `hover()`.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.place').hover(function(){ //Style on hover 
            $('.anHour').css({"background": " #9bcc41"});
            },    
            function(){ //Style when not hovered
            $('.anHour').css({"background": "none"});   
            });         

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery:

```js
$('.place td').mouseenter(function() {
 $('.anHour').addClass('hover');
}).mouseleave(function() {
 $('.anHour').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.anHour.hover {
    background-color: red;
}
.anHour:hover ~ tr {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr class="anHour">
      <td class="hour" rowspan="3">9:00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="place">                                       
      <td>Place 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="place">
      <td>Place 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>                               
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to look at css selectors.

This is possible only if the element to be affected is placed BEFORE the triggering element.

### css

```
.place:hover ~ .anHour {
    /*code here*/
}
```

What the above code will do is on hover of any .place element, it will trigger the css on all .anHour sibling elements.

Another way to do it is using jquery

### Jquery

```
$(function() {
  $('.place').hover(function() {
    $('.anhour').css();
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('.anhour').css();
  });
});
```

Comment: Pretty please give me an explanation as to why it got downvoted.